# Vertical navbar gets longer when elements are above it?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a vertical navbar on the left of the page which is as long as the website (i.e. stretches down to the footer). However, it is only the right height when there is nothing above it - when I add the site's title, the navbar gets longer than the site.

```css
body{  
        padding: 0px;
        margin: 10px auto 0 auto;
        font-family: 'corbel','arial';
        background: #fff;
        color: #444; /* text colour */
        max-width: 1500px;
        height: auto;
        position: relative;
       }

      footer{
     background: #333;
       color: #fff;
       padding: .1em 3em;
       width: auto; 
        margin-left: 130px;
       }
      h1{
       text-align: center;
       font-size: 85px;
          padding: 10px;
         margin: auto;
          margin-top: 10px;
       }
       #content{
       margin-left: 150px;
       }
      /* Navbar */
       #navbar{
       background-color: #599;
       list-style-type: none;
       overflow: hidden;
       width: 130px;
       margin: 0px;
 

    font-family: 'corbel','arial';
     text-align: center;
     padding-left: 0px;
     height: 100%;
     float: left;
     position: absolute; 
    }
    #nav_li{
     
     text-align: center;
    }
    #nav_a{
     text-decoration: none; 
     margin: 10px;
     display: inline-block;
     color: white;
    }
```

```html
        <h1>Website Title</h1>
<body>
 <ul id='navbar'>
  <li id='nav_li'><a id='nav_a' href='index.html'>Home</a></li>
  <li id='nav_li'><a id='nav_a' href='gallery.html'>Gallery</a></li>
  <li id='nav_li'><a id='nav_a' href='reviews.html'>Our reviews</a></li>
 </ul>
 <div id='nav_fill'> </div>

 <div id='content'>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
 </div> 
 <footer>
   <p>Content &copy; Business Name - Website design &copy;</p>
 </footer>
</body>
```

Big thanks to anyone who can help!

Comment: Here's a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/716o4ae0/

Comment: Eh... yes? You have it set to 100%, and then you add an element above it. I fail to see the problem? It does exactly what it's supposed to do.

Comment: Also, your `<h1>` is outside of `<body>`??

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways of fixing this problem - the easiest is to just put the `html, body` background color as the sidebar in CSS (with `height: 100%`), then add a sticky `header` and `footer` at the top and bottom, and put a background-color on the container-element.

Something like this:

```css
* { margin: 0; padding: 0;}
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  background: blue;
  }
#content {
  background: white;
 }
h1 {
  background: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 3em;
  }
#menu {
  margin-top: 3.5em;
  float: left;
  width: 7em;
  color: white;
  }
#content {
  background: white;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 3em 0 4em 7em;
  padding-top: 3.5em;
  }
footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 4em;
  background: gray;
  }
```

```html
<body>
  <h1>This is a heading</h1>
  <ul id="menu">
     <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
  </ul>
  <div id="content">
    <p>Something goes in here</p>
  </div>
 <footer>This is the footer</footer>
 </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `position:fixed`, and `min/max-height` i also suggest to use `calc()`, to calculate good size of navbar.
Here You have [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h8fpy6qw/)